# JS push arrays to main array with key name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `solidIcons` which contains:

```
['book', 'apple', 'smile', 'pencil']
```

and `regularIcons`:

```
['flower', 'clock', 'house', 'bird']
```

I want to create the following array from the two:

```
{ 
  'solid-icons': ['book', 'apple', 'smile', 'pencil'], 
  'regular-icons': ['flower', 'clock', 'house', 'bird'], 
}
```

The goal is to be able to use `map` to loop through either `solid-icons` or `regular-icons`.

I'm trying:

```
let allIcons = [];

allIcons["solid-icons"] = solidIcons;
allIcons["regular-icons"] = regularIcons;
```

This is creating

```
0: [solid-icons: Array()] 
1: [regular-icons: Array()]
```

The issue is that O cannot simply access an array group with `allIcons["solid-icons"]` I have to use the index `allIcons[0]`. How can i create the array in such a way that i can use the `solid-icons` or `regular-icons` to access without the index.

Comment: `allIcons["solid-icons"] = solidIcons`

Comment: *"I want to create the following array from the two:"* That's not an array, that's an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let allIcons = []` - this is array, you need `let allIcons = {}`  instead

```js
let allIcons = {};

allIcons["solid-icons"] = solidIcons;
allIcons["regular-icons"] = regularIcons;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just use object literal:

```
let allIcons = { 
  'solid-icons': ['book', 'apple', 'smile', 'pencil'], 
  'regular-icons': ['flower', 'clock', 'house', 'bird'], 
}
```

You are not creating an array but object.